# core data - fetch attribute that match one of the values in an array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

My core data model:

```
Person 
======
personId  (NSNumber)
```

This is a basic core data question,
I have an array of personIds (not `Person`, just `NSNumber` of ids) and I want to fetch all the `Persons` with corresponding id in the array.

This is how I fetch a person that correspond to one id:

```
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
   request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"personId = %@", onePersonId];
```

I'm looking for a way to fetch multiple persons that match to multiple ids

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use 'IN' match for this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"personId IN %@", idsArray];
```

Comment: Its good that Swift can do this much at least. I am used to raw SQL queries which give the real power, but Core Data is very limiting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which creates predicate which you are looking for using block.

```
NSPredicate *predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Person *person, NSDictionary *bind){
    return [arrayOfIds containsObject:person.personId]; //check whether person id is contained within your array of IDs
}];
```

Comment: Note that block-based predicates (and Objective-C based predicates in general) cannot be used with a Core Data fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
let ids: [NSNumber] = [1234, 5678]
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "YourEntityName")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", ids)
```

Full Example:

```
func getAllThings(withIds ids: [NSNumber]) -> [Thing] {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Thing")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", ids)

    do {
        if let things = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Thing] {
            return things
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // handle error
    }

    return []
}
```